# SonarQube 'assertThat' causes 'assertions should not be used in production code'

Tags: java, sonarqube, assert

In our SonarQube integration I've noticed the use of `org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat` causes a bug. Namely

```
Assertions should not be used in production code
 
Bug
 
Major
java:S5960
 
Assertions are intended to be used in test code, but not in production code. It is confusing, and might lead to ClassNotFoundException when the build tools only provide the required dependency in test scope.
In addition, assertions will throw a sub-class of Error: AssertionError, which should be avoided in production code.
This rule raises an issue when any assertion intended to be used in test is used in production code.
Supported frameworks:
 - JUnit
 - FestAssert
 - AssertJ
Note: this does not apply for assert from Java itself or if the source code package name is related to tests (contains: test or assert or junit).
```

Technically it's right as this code, which is test code, does not have `test` for example in the package name or even the path. But if the code is switched across to `org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals` the problem goes away.

Any ideas what's happening here?

Comment: When you change to springframework, Sonar rule probably is not checking those packages/classes. Only the three frameworks that the rule supports: JUnit, FestAssert and AssertJ. If it is test code should be on the src/test. The issue appears in SonarQube interface or in an integration with an IDE?

Comment: Ah - that makes sense, namely the switch from `assertj` to `springframework`. Sonar does not recognise it as an assertion framework, I guess. There is still confusion here though. This issue appears on a new test class. Other test classes use `assertThat` without problem. The warning shows up on both the SonarQube website and the IDE SonarLint plugin. The code is under `src/main` as this is a standalone integration test module. Renaming it to `src/test` does not fix the issue. Adding `test` to the package name does, but should not be required based on the other test classes.

Comment: Ran SonarLint against one of the existing test classes and it caught the `assertThat` issue too. I'm guessing the baseline set on the project is excluding it from being reported on the website. So the solution here seems to be to `test` on the package name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To provide an answer, the solution I ended up taking was to rename the package to include `test` in the name. e.g.

> com.project.integration.test;

This feels invasive but it was the lesser evil.